# JavaScriptを使ったゲームで、ゲームオーバー時にキー入力を無効化をしたい

Tags: javascript

初めて投稿させていただきます。

JavaScriptで簡単なゲーム開発をしております。
今の課題はプレイヤーが敵に当たった時にキーを無効化して操作をできないようにすることです。
現在はプレイヤーが敵に当たってもゲームオーバーのテキストのみ表示され、キーを押すとまた操作が可能になってしまいます。

調べたところキーを無効化するには、プレイヤーが敵に当たったら、 `return false` を返すようにしてあげればいいという情報を得たのですが、私の書いてる場所が間違っているのか、他に書かなければならないコードが他にあるのか、 `return false` を返してくれず、キーの操作が有効になっています。

`return false` はイベントハンドラーの中に書きました。

```
addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key == "ArrowUp") {
    sy -= 62.5;
    if (sy < 0) {
      sy = 32.5;
    }
  } else if (event.key == "ArrowDown") {
    sy += 62.5;
    if (sy > 500) {
      sy = 467.5;
    }
  } else if (event.key == "ArrowLeft") {
    sx -= 62.5;
    if (sx < 0) {
      sx = 32.5;
    }
  } else if (event.key == "ArrowRight") {
    sx += 62.5;
    if (sx > 500) {
      sx = 467.5;
    }
  }
  if (sx == ex && sy == ey) {
    return drawGameOver();　　　　
    return event.key = false;　
  }

  draw();
});
```

`return false` を書く適切な位置がもし分かる方、キーを有効化するために他にどのようなコードが必要になるか
分かる方教えてください。

Answer (score 2):

イベントハンドラで `return false` した場合は、その処理中のイベントについてだけ、ブラウザのデフォルトの挙動をキャンセルします。デフォルトの挙動というのは、「テキストフィールドに文字を挿入する」「スペースキーでスクロール」などです。

この場合、キャンセルしたいのはブラウザのデフォルトの挙動ではないので、`return false` は関係ありません。

イベントハンドラの中でゲームがどういう状態かをチェックできるようにして、ゲームオーバー後だったら一切処理をしないようにすればよいでしょう。

```
const State = {
  PLAYING: 0,
  GAME_OVER: 1
};
let gameState = State.PLAYING;

addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  // ゲームオーバー後だったら何もしない
  if (gameState === State.GAME_OVER)
    return;

  // プレイ中はカーソルキーを処理する
  console.assert(gameState === State.PLAYING);
  if (event.key == "ArrowUp") {
    ...
  if (sx == ex && sy == ey) {
    gameState = State.GAME_OVER;
    drawGameOver();
    return;
  }

  draw();
});
```

Comment: 解決できました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @MotoyasuTomoko 解決した場合は承認をお願いします。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour